# Using schtasks on Windows XP to Stop a Task After Running for a Specific Amount of Time

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler

How would I use the schtasks command line tool on Windows XP to stop a task after it runs for a specific amount of time? The help page at [enter link description here](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/schtasks.mspx?mfr=true) does not explain how to do this even though it lists this as an option when querying the task. [image: Stop task option in Windows Scheduled Tasks]

Answer (score 0):

If all else fails, you can create a second scheduled task that ends the first task at a certain time.  It would probably be less CPU intensive and I think schtasks is a service anyway, always in the background.

aAlso, on windows 7 the option `/DU` sets the "duration" of the task, and I do think it ends the task afterwards.  Similarly, setting `/ST` and `/ET` ("start time" and "end time") will kill the task after the end time has passed, though that doesn't seem to apply here.

I do think that all scheduled tasks are automatically killed after a certain period of time.  Additionally, `schtasks /Create /?` on windows 7 states `For /V1 tasks, if /RI is specified, duration defaults to 1 hour` where "/V1 tasks" are tasks that have been created to be compatible with pre-vista versions of windows.  With that in mind, that probably means that any task made from the command line defaults to 1 hour anyway, and it's possible that a kill-time is *required*, since you need a default for pre-vista tasks to be happy.